# "in which", "to which" are these subordinate conjunctions?

Tags: conjunctions, subordinate-clauses

> 1. This is the bag **in which I put my sandwich**.
> 2. I shall return the money to the person **to which it belongs**.

"to which it belongs" and "in which I put my sandwich" are these subordinate / dependent clauses?

"***in which***, ***to which***" are these subordinate conjunctions?

Comment: Where did you get these sentences?

Comment: I think you are correct, however neither of these sentence is grammatically correct. These should be:  "I shall return to **the** home *which belongs to me*" and "I shall return to **the** home *in which he lives*"

Comment: "**This is the bag I put my sandwich in**" and "**I shall return the money to the person it belongs to**" - that's how I would say it.

Comment: @user123 No, they are not subordinating conjunctions, but preposition phrases, and 2. is **wrong** -- it should be "to **whom**" it belongs". 1. is OK -- "which" is a relative pronoun and "in which I put my sandwich" is a subordinate relative clause.

Comment: @BillJ Actually my doubt is "in which, of which, to which" are these equivalent to subordinators?

Comment: @BillJ Could you please refer this sight and then answer me http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv286.shtml

Comment: @BillJ In which and at which are sometimes used as more precise sounding alternatives to where to introduce relative clauses after nouns referring to place:
Near where I live there's a wood where you can find woodpeckers.
Near where I live there's a wood in which you can find woodpeckers. Here "in which" used as equivalent of "where". "where" is not subordinator here?

Comment: You asked if "in which" and "to which" were subordinating conjunctions and were told very clearly that they are not -- they are preposition phrases. The fact that some other expression can be used instead is irrelevant. And, no, "where" is not a subordinator. In traditional grammar, "where" is a relative adverb. Look here: [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/where)

Comment: @BillJ  High School English Grammar and Composition by Wren & Martin. This is a traditional grammar book. In this only the writers mentioned look here:- 403. The chief Subordinating Conjunctions are:-
After, because, if, that, though, although, till, before, unless, as, when, where, while.

Comment: Here some comments are deleted?!!

Answer (score 1):

Answers in comments:

> @SovereignSun:
>
> "This is the bag I put my sandwich in" and "I shall return the money to the person it belongs to" - that's how I would say it.

and

> @BillJ:
>
> No, they are not subordinating conjunctions, but preposition phrases
>
> Sentence 1. is OK -- "which" is a relative pronoun and "in which I put my sandwich" is a subordinate relative clause.
>
> Sentence 2. is wrong -- it should be "to **whom**" it belongs".